# jackson objectmapper conversion from json string to object gives null values

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, objectmapper

I have below java class with json annotations.

```
public class NotificationResponse {
@JsonProperty(
    value = "TransactionId",
    required = false
)
private String transactionId;
@JsonProperty(
    value = "DateTime",
    required = true
)
private DateTime dateTime;
@JsonProperty(
    value = "Status",
    required = true
)
private String status;
@JsonProperty(
    value = "EventType",
    required = true
)
private String eventType;
@JsonProperty(
    value = "ItineraryNumber",
    required = false
)
private String itineraryNumber;
@JsonProperty(
    value = "ConfirmationNumber",
    required = false
)
private String confirmationNumber;

public NotificationResponse() {
}
}
```

And below one is the json string getting back from server.

```
{"TransactionId": "f06edfa3-27f4-44e6-838c-b8dd3d0a3210","Date": "2016-11-21T02:05:00+0000","Status": "SUCCESS","EventType": "CANCEL","ItineraryNumber": "7152088262"}
```

I want this string to be converted to above said object and I am using below code for conversion.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
    return mapper.readValue(response, NotificationResponse.class);
```

But I am getting NotificationResponse object mapped with null values for elements.

```
transactionId = null
 dateTime = null
 status = null
 eventType = null
 itineraryNumber = null
 partnerConfirmationNumber = null
```

Could someone help me to solve this?

Comment: the properties are private. Jackson does not populate such fields. does the class have public setter methods?

Comment: or you can tell jackson to deserialize private fields - `mapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);`